# kendo tabstrip with multiple div on the same tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, strip-tags

I have a tabstring

```
<div id="tabstrip">
   <ul>
     <li>tab1</li>
     <li> tab2 </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have the javasrcript code

```
$('#tabstrip').kendoTabStrip({
    contentURL: ["TAB1","tab2"]
});
```

On the tab2 I have 2 separate divs. for tab2 I have

```
<div id="tab2"></div><div tab3></div>
```

on click on something in the first `div` redirect to div 3 in the sale `ul`.

Comment: and what is the problem??

Comment: under tab2 i have 2 divs. div 1 and div 2. When i click something in div1 redirects me to div 2. but div 2 is a cshtml, and does not have the kendo ui tabstrip. How can I do, that div 1 and div 2 share the same tabstrip?

Comment: can ou create the fiddle

Comment: I can explain again. If no, I will create a fiddle. Under tab2 there is a <div id="1"</div> . I have a separate cshtml, which I would like to bind it's content undet tab2. How can I do that? The first div appears under tab2, because of the contentUrl in $('#tabstrip').

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so that it will be easy to help

Comment: in the end i didn't needed the tabstrip fr the sendond div. i needed a  jquery popup. thx!